# What is the difference between OCR and Recognize Text in Azure Pricing Page

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

As I found in https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/cognitive-services/computer-vision/, OCR has different price against Recognize Text. It is quite confusing. What is the difference? I can't find any clue thru the documents.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The difference is described here in the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/concept-recognizing-text#ocr-optical-character-recognition-api

In a few words:

- OCR is synchronous, uses an earlier recognition model but works with more languages
- Recognize Text (and Read API, its successor) uses updated recognition models, but is asynchronous.

If you want to process handwritten text for example, you should use the 2nd one